# count missing value pandas dataframe, using np.argwhere

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have e dataframe like this:

RTD  I
0 BA  32 
1 BA  15
2 BA  22
3 BA  75
4 BA  28
5 BA  32 
6 BA  7

Now, i would to count the minimum and the maximun number of rows consecutives where of the number 32 is not present

Code is ( refer:@MaxU):

len(x) - np.argwhere(x.I==32).max() - 1
out= 1 (it's right)

len(x) - np.argwhere(x.I==32).min() - 1
Out= 6 (It is wrong, because the result should be 4

The solution that i found is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'RTD': ['BA']*7, 'I': [32, 15, 22, 75, 28, 32, 7]})
print (df )
```

## For calculate the max e min delay:

```
def rolling_count(val):
    if val == rolling_count.previous:
        rolling_count.count +=1
    else:
        rolling_count.previous = val
        rolling_count.count = 1
    return rolling_count.count
rolling_count.count = 0 #static variable
rolling_count.previous = None #static variable


df['count'] = df['I']==32
ddf= df['count'].apply(rolling_count)
print ('delay maximum',max(ddf))

DelayMinimum= len(df) - np.argwhere(df.I==32).max() - 1
print(DelayMinimum)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'count the minimum and maximum time missing'? There are no missing values.

Comment: The number 32,scrolling down the column, is present in position 0 and 5. I would count  the max of the rows consecutives where the number 32 is not present, e the min of the rows consecutives where the number 32 is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the values 32 and then take the the first difference of the index if your index is ordered 0 to n-1.

```
np.diff(np.append(-2, df.query('I==32').index.values)) -1
```

I don't understand the very first value but this should get you very close.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'diff'

Comment: My mistake. There is no differencing with the index. Use numpy diff function

Comment: Hi. It's very difficult resolve this question. Maybe is necessary a loop founded on len of index where the condition is true.

Comment: No, no loop is necessary. The above code does what I understand the question to be.

Comment: @Andreas check now. I had to append -2 to the front of the array to get the first value to match yours.

Answer (score 0):

A bit robust solution but it works. I included whole code so you can correct me if I misinterpreted something:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'RTD': ['BA']*7, 'I': [32, 15, 22, 75, 28, 32, 7]})
occurrences = df[df['I'] == 32].min(axis=1).index.values
max_diff = 0
for i in range(len(occurrences)-1):
    curr_diff = occurrences[i + 1] - occurrences[i] - 1
    if  curr_diff > max_diff:
        max_diff = curr_diff

min_diff = len(df['I'])
occurrences = np.append(occurrences, min_diff - 1)

for i in range(len(occurrences)-1):
    curr_diff = occurrences[i + 1] - occurrences[i]
    if  curr_diff < min_diff:
        min_diff = curr_diff
```

Comment: @Andreas I think that this code covers your question for minimum and maximum delay between occurrences. Which part doesn't seem ok?